# t-sql grouping query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

based on the following table

```
Name
---------
A
A
A
B
B
C
C
C
```

I want to add another column to this table called 'OnGoing' and the values should alternate for each group of names.
There are only two values 'X' and 'Y'. So the table will look like

```
Name     OnGoing
----------------
A        X
A        X
A        X 
B        Y
B        Y
C        X
C        X 
C        X
```

how to write such a query that can alternate the values for each group of names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Name VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'A'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'A' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'A' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'B' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'B' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'C' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'C' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'C' 

SELECT  *,
        CASE 
            WHEN RowNum % 2 = 0 
                THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'X'
        END
FROM    @Table t INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Name,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) RowNum
            FROM    @Table
            GROUP BY Name
        ) sub ON t.Name = sub.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

Alter your table to include the new column:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD
    OnGoing char(1) NULL
GO
```

and then try this:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (Name char(1), OnGoing char(1))
INSERT @YourTable Values ('A',NULL)
INSERT @YourTable Values ('A',NULL)
INSERT @YourTable Values ('A',NULL)
INSERT @YourTable Values ('B',NULL)
INSERT @YourTable Values ('B',NULL)
INSERT @YourTable Values ('C',NULL)
INSERT @YourTable Values ('C',NULL)
INSERT @YourTable Values ('C',NULL)


;WITH TableRows AS
(
 SELECT
     *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) AS RowID
     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
               *
               FROM @YourTable
          ) dt
)
UPDATE y
    SET OnGoing=CASE
                   WHEN r.RowID % 2 = 1 THEN 'X'
                   ELSE 'Y'
                END
    FROM @YourTable           y
        INNER JOIN TableRows  r ON y.Name=r.Name

SELECT * FROM @YourTable
```

OUTPUT:

```
Name OnGoing
---- -------
A    X
A    X
A    X
B    Y
B    Y
C    X
C    X
C    X

(8 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: +1 This is clearly the best answer, since you're actually updating the original table as requested, and since CTEs are the hot thing.

Comment: I agree this is more close to what i needed. But since the core logic is same i granted answer to the earliest reply.. for now its one up vote from me.. Thanks a lot KM.

Comment: If only I hadn't had the 5 minute distraction that slowed down my reply!... ;-o

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
select
    t1.Name,
    sub1.OnGoing 
from
    TableOne t1
    INNER JOIN 
(select
    Name,
    CASE RANK() over (order by Name) % 2
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Y'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'X'
    END as OnGoing
from 
    TableOne 
group by Name) sub1 ON sub1.Name = t1.Name
```

This is the actual output from my test:

```
Name OnGoing
---- -------
A    X
A    X
A    X
B    Y
B    Y
C    X
C    X
C    X
```